# Sub Navigations are showing up

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

Im have a problem with the navigation im working with. in this [LINK](http://codepen.io/iammelo88/pen/CBdEe), when you hover the menu > ul, all of its sub links shows up. im not sure what happened but im using this [theme from themeforest](http://themeforest.net/item/inspiro-b-premium-responsive-theme-for-drupal-7/full_screen_preview/3854468). Please help. Thanks

```
<li class="dropdown" id="el1">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Schools</a>
```

Comment: I see many problems with this menu, and the it doesn't look like the original menu is made for multilevel menus? And do you want the menu horizontal or vertical.

Comment: @Beowolve its originally a horizontal menu